# How to get a output_url from python terminal and store it

Tags: python, api, http, url, request

i need helping getting a output url from the Python terminal, it's a pretty simple code:

```
    r = requests.post(
    "https://api.deepai.org/api/deepdream",
    data={
        'image': 'xxxxx', # url image
    },
    headers={'api-key': 'xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'}
 )
 print(r.json())
```

This code gets me a 'output_url' in the terminal, looks like that:

```
{'id': 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx', 'output_url': 'https://api.deepai.org/job-view-file/xxxxxxx/outputs/output.jpg'}
```

i need to get that url and store in a variable (should be enough)

ps: I'm using Python 3.9.1 64bit

Comment: Maybe `r.json()['output_url']`..?

Comment: Thx @RustamGarayev, it seems to work in some way, but i don't know where the output is going now, it doesn't show up in the terminal and i don't have any .json in the project

Comment: Assuming `print(r.json())` gives you the below data, you can store output url like: `url = r.json()['output_url']`. Then printing `url` will give you desired value.

Comment: Thank you very much! worked perfectly!